# In Emacs' org-mode, any way to hide the subtree with timestamp not set to today?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, timestamp, to-do

I just started to learn [org-mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode) (and [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)) and I plan to use it as a *calendar/timetable/todo-list hybrid*. Is it possible to hide entries with timestamp not set to today? If so, how?

For example, say if today is 2014-09-18:

```
* Lunch

* TODO Call boss
  <2014-09-18 Thu 13:30pm>

   ** Report :: Nothing happened

* TODO Call Bob                             ; This entry will not be shown
  <2014-09-19 Fri 13:30pm>                  ; This entry will not be shown
                                            ; This entry will not be shown
   ** Discuss :: Project Alice              ; This entry will not be shown
   ** Discuss :: Upgrading to CentOS 5      ; This entry will not be shown

* TODO Fetch Claire from school
```

Incidentally, are there any more efficient way to deal with calendar/timetable/todo-lists in org-mode?

P.S.> I posted this question on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147567/in-emacs-org-mode-any-way-to-hide-the-subtree-with-timestamp-not-set-to-today) but didn't get an answer so far so I repost it here.

Comment: How about generating an agenda buffer that excludes those entries, instead of trying to hide an entry in the master todo file?  See the section in the manual relating to agenda views:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Views.html  See the section of the manual relating to `org-agenda-custom-commands`:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html

Comment: Reading through the sections. And since I'm new to Emacs, I'm referring to Emacs manual on default key-bindings, how to set variable, syntax for list in Elips, etc. Feels like I'm spending more time trying to be productive than be productive. LOL

Comment: Another idea you may wish to explore is using the function `org-sort-entries`, which can be used to sort the master todo file entries by date, time, name, priority, etc.  I have a custom function that I use that performs several sorts in a row:  a, o, p, t.

Answer (score 1):

Sparse trees may be the answer.
Hit C-c / in your buffer
This will bring up a menu-ish thing in the mini buffer.
You can select various date functions ([b]efore, [a]after, [D]ates range etc.
Play around a little bit to determine exactly what you want. Note there are
by default 3 kinds of timestamps that a date range will catch, bare ,
DEADLINE , and SCHEDULED 
There are also a lot of agenda types that might get you what you want